# Get the version of a exe or dll from inno setup

Tags: delphi, inno-setup, pascal

How I can get the version number from a exe file or a dll using Inno, I tried the `GetFileVersion` function but only is available in the Inno Preprocessor (and I need use this function in the `[Code]` section of my script) . Also I tried the [`GetFileVersionInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647003%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function but is not recognized by Inno.

Comment: Essentially no WinAPI function declarations are available in Inno Setup's Pascal script, but you are always free to call any function in any DLL by declaring it yourself. For instance, `GetFileVersionInfo` resides in `version.dll`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try

```
function GetVersionNumbers(const Filename: String; var VersionMS, VersionLS: Cardinal): Boolean;
```

and/or

```
function GetVersionNumbersString(const Filename: String; var Version: String): Boolean;
```